# SendTo / Batch / 7zip

Tags: windows, batch-file, 7zip, sendto

I am trying to create a SendTo shortcut to a batch script that will take the selected files (in this case, jpg's), zip them with 7zip and name them the folder name (that the selected files are in) and place them in the same folder. The directory names have spaces in them too. 
I am real close but have hit a stump..

Here's what I've got so far..

`@echo off
    set folder=%~dp1
    if exist "%folder%- Photos.zip" del "%folder%- Photos.zip"
    "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z" a -mx9 -tzip "%folder%- Photos.zip" "%~dp1*.jpg"
    pause`

It is doing just about everything I want, except not naming the zip file right. It always ends up "- Photos.zip" in the directory that I want.

Any help? 
Thanks in advance..

Comment: I see `7z` follows exactly your file name formula: `"%folder%- Photos.zip"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just specifying `C:\folder\ - Photos.zip` but you want `C:\folder\folder - Photos.zip`

Try this to get the folder and filename prefix separately:

```
set folder=%~dp1
set filename=%~p1
set filename=%filename:~1,-1%
```

Couldn't try this because my tablet does not have a dosbox ;-)

Then 7z this way:

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z" a -mx9 -tzip "%folder%%filename% - Photos.zip" "%~dp1*.jpg"
```

If you want to debug this, you should add

```
echo folder is %folder% >> C:\temp\batch.log
echo filename is %filename% >> C:\temp\batch.log
```

and investigate that file later on.

Comment: Nice! I used this instead, it works better :P 
Thanks @Marged

Answer (score 0):

Ended up coming up with this and it works!

```
@echo off

set folder=%~dp1
IF %folder:~-1%==\ SET folder=%folder:~0,-1%

set name=%~p1
if %name:~-1%==\ set name=%name:~0,-1%


if exist "%folder%%name% - Photos.zip" del "%folder%%name% - Photos.zip"

"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z" a -mx9 -tzip "%folder%%name% - Photos.zip" "%~dp1*.jpg"
```